# [Java]Declaring Multidimensional Array within loop

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
String[][] aS= new String[16][3];

String[] s0 ={"FIELD0", "FIELD1", "FIELD2"};
String[] s1 ={"FIELD0", "FIELD1", "FIELD2"};
String[] s2 ={"FIELD0", "FIELD1", "FIELD2"}; ...
String[] s15 ={"FIELD0", "FIELD1", "FIELD2"};

for(int i=0;i<aS.length;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        //error!
        aS[i][j]= s+"i"+[j];   //s0[0],s0[1]...s15[3]
    }
}
```

Im familiar with multidimensional arrays, im just not abot to figure out how this part can be fixed: " s+"i"+[j]; "

Edit:[error]
Syntax error on token "+", Expression expected after this token

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: Syntax error on token "+", Expression expected after this token

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in Java (and in most programming languages), it doesn't support *dynamic naming*.

If you want to use `s0`, `s1` or any other array, you should write it, for example:

```
aS[i][j]= s0[j];
```

Comment: yup, but then i'd have to keep chanding s0,s1,s2; manually. i'd labelled them numbers hoping i could change 0,1,2... within a loop

Answer (score 1):

First of all in Java you cannot create dynamic names of variables. So

```
aS[i][j]= s+"i"+[j];   //s0[0],s0[1]...s15[3]
```

is incorrect

```
String[][] aS= new String[16][3];
```

This means you can have 16 1D String arrays each of size 3 i.e 3 Strings in each array.

```
for(int i=0;i<aS.length;i++)
{
        aS[i]= yourArray  //s0[0],s0[1]...s15[3]
}
```

Here `yourArray` should be String[] with size 3 similar to your S0 - S15.

or you can do

```
for(int i=0;i<aS.length;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        aS[i][j]= "FIELD" + j;
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried doing this: aS[i][j]= "s"+i[j]; now the error is: "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to int"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **initialize** your **multidimensional** array you can do it like this:

```
String[][] aS = { {"FIELD0", "FIELD1", "FIELD2"},
                  {"FIELD0", "FIELD1", "FIELD2"}, 
                  {"FIELD0", "FIELD1", "FIELD2"},
                  ...
                  {"FIELD0", "FIELD1", "FIELD2"} };
```

Comment: yup,creating separate arrays just looked neat, i guess i'd go with this if looping isnt possible :)